# How to save a label's image to a UIPasteboard? Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimage, uilabel, uipasteboard

How can you save a label's image to a UIPasteboard / Clipboard in Objective C - Xcode 7.1?
I've tried this code bellow, but it only copies the text.

```
[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string = helloField.text;
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
pasteboard.string = @"paste me somewhere";
```

Is there away to copy the image as well or even just copying the image by its self?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.

You need to use the following method to put one image to the native iOS Pasteboard:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];    
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setImage:image];
```

You also can to put array of UIImages to UIPasteboard:

```
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setImages:arrayOfImages];
```

To learn more information you can read the Apple [UIPasteboard class reference.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/)